# Protecting my app files(Android Studio)

Tags: android, image, file

Well hello, im working on a app that take a picture and then save it into the external storage, the problem that i get is when i use a external app, to clean up the cell phone memory, this kind of apps get into the folder where the pictures located, then deleted everything on it, i realy don't have any idea to protect them.

sorry for the problems with my English is not my native tongue

Comment: Store the picture to internal memory instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not yours. The problem is your cleaner's. Modify the cleaner's settings. Android cleaner like **Clean Master** is just weird. I don't know what kind of cleaning they do! Once they deleted my 150+ apps from my SD Card. So, if you are tensed about protecting your files from being deleted then it is worthless. You can't. Ok, think, a user is not using any cleaner to keep his/her phone tidy. But what will you do or how you will protect your files when the user is going to delete those files himself/herself?
The one thing you can do is - by achieving SuperUser permission from a user, you can just modify the SD Card's W/O or R/O system. But it has also some disadvantages. If you do something lile this, then you app may be introduced as a malicious program by your user. So, afterall, the answer is it isn't possible...

Answer (score 0):

You should use:
getFilesDir()
This folder is located inside Android/data/data/your_package/ so no app except yours has access to it (unless it has root permission).